# Uploading and saving images

Tags: java, android, android-activity, bitmap, parse-platform

I am experiencing issues in completing these lines of codes:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), /*to be retrieved from image view */);"
```

where I would want the getResources to be retrieved not from my `Drawable` but from the `ImageView`, where the picture of the imageview is being displayed from the user image gallery (shortly user will be able to upload images from facebook into their imageview as well).

In brief, I am trying to have the users upload their image (profile picture) into parse as part of their profile creation page where they would have to fill out various information. Users would be able to preview their picture in an image view.

Below is the complete code:

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                 /* This is the section where the images is converted, saved, and uploaded. I have not been able Locate the image from the ImageView, where the user uploads the picture to imageview from either their gallery and later on from facebook */ 
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        /*to be retrieved from image view */);
                // Convert it to byte
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

                // Create the ParseFile
                ParseFile file = new ParseFile("profilePicture.png", image);
                // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
                file.saveinBackground();



                // Create a column named "Profile Picture" and set the string
                currentUser.put("ImageName", "Profile Picture");

                // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
                currentUser.put("ProfilePicture", file);

                // Create the class and the columns

                currentUser.put("name", name); 
                currentUser.put("age", age); 
                currentUser.put("headline", headline); 
                currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        if (e == null) {
                            // Success!
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, MoodActivity.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Below is the entire activity code

```
public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {

     private String currentUserId;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
        private ArrayList<String> names;
        private ListView usersListView;
        private Button logoutButton;
        String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
        String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
        Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Distance");


        String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender");
        Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
        Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.matching);

            logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
            logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ParseUser.logOut();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            setConversationsList();
        }
        private void setConversationsList() {
            currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
            names = new ArrayList<String>();
          // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

               ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

             //  query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

               query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
               // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
               query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
               // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
               query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
               query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
               query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Minimum_Age", minimumAge);
               query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Maximum_Age", maximumAge);
        //     query.whereWithinKilometers("Maximum_Distance", point, maxDistance)





            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                            names.add(userList.get(i).getUsername().toString());
                        }

                        usersListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                        namesArrayAdapter =
                            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                        usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                        usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                                openConversation(names, i);
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
            query.whereEqualTo("username", names.get(pos));
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
               public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
                   if (e == null) {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                       intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                       startActivity(intent);
                   } else {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                           "Error finding that user",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you want to retrieve the underlying `Bitmap` of an `ImageView` ?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. That is correct, as are already able to upload a picture from their gallery and preview it in the imageview. My goal now is to store the image that they see in the imageview into parse, so that I could retrieve it late.r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you said, you can assume the underlying resource of your `ImageView` is a `BitmapDrawable`, so you should be able to get it like this :

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) myImgView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

---

If what's stated above is not true for any reason, you can do some other trick which is : subclassing `ImageView` overriding the `onDraw` method, and have the image drawn on a `Bitmap` of your own like this :

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    private Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(...);

    /*
     * Constructors, etc ...
     */

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return myBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Unfortunately there's no Canvas.getBitmap, so need to be set every time
        canvas.setBitmap(getBitmap());
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Note that this is not guaranteed to display correctly the image, just to copy it ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Your help has help resolved my issue.